# Removing duplicate legend bar plot matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to edit my legend to make it only shows the labels once
I use for loop to create my bar graph. **How can I remove the duplicate legend?** It should only show week and month once

This code give me the graph below

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))
ax.set(xlim=(0,6))
ax.set(ylim=(0,150))
ax.set_xticklabels(edgeslist)

for i in range(6):
    plt.bar(x = i, data = classw.iloc[:,i], 
            height = len(classw.iloc[:,i]) - classw.iloc[:,i].isna().sum(), 
            color = (0.91, 0.1, 0.4, 1), label = 'week',
            align = 'edge', width = -0.4)
    plt.bar(x = i, data = classm.iloc[:,i], 
            height = len(classm.iloc[:,i]) - classm.iloc[:,i].isna().sum(), 
            color = 'blue', label = 'month',
            align = 'edge', width = 0.4)

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom legend containing only the elements you want using the following code

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

r = Patch(facecolor=(0.91,0.1,0.4,1.0), label='week')
b = Patch(facecolor='blue', label='month')

plt.legend(handles=[r,b])
plt.show()
```

Which would give you a legend like this

[image]

Refer to [this page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html) for more on making custom legends.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1** You can set the legend inside the loop only if a condition is met:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))
ax.set(xlim=(0,6))
ax.set(ylim=(0,150))
ax.set_xticklabels(edgeslist)

for i in range(6):
    plt.bar(x = i, data = classw.iloc[:,i], 
            height = len(classw.iloc[:,i]) - classw.iloc[:,i].isna().sum(), 
            color = (0.91, 0.1, 0.4, 1), label = 'week',
            align = 'edge', width = -0.4)
    plt.bar(x = i, data = classm.iloc[:,i], 
            height = len(classm.iloc[:,i]) - classm.iloc[:,i].isna().sum(), 
            color = 'blue', label = 'month',
            align = 'edge', width = 0.4)
     if i==0:
        ax.legend()
```

**Method 2**
You can create a `list` with the label name. You will set as `None` but one value, then in the plot code, you index the label list this way.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))
ax.set(xlim=(0,6))
ax.set(ylim=(0,150))
ax.set_xticklabels(edgeslist)

label_week = [None]*6
label_week[5] = 'week'

label_month = [None]*6
label_month[5] = 'month'

for i in range(6):
    plt.bar(x = i, data = [1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 1], 
            height = 5, 
            color = (0.91, 0.1, 0.4, 1), label = label_week[i],
            align = 'edge', width = -0.4)
    plt.bar(x = i, data = [1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 1], 
            height = 6, 
            color = 'blue', label = label_month[i],
            align = 'edge', width = 0.4)

plt.legend()
```

Hope it helps.